# Send Datetime From Jquery to MVC action

Tags: jquery, ajax, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-4

I want to send Datetime from View using Jquery,
For this I am using a function as,

```
 if (operation === "read") {
            var scheduler = $("#scheduler").data("kendoScheduler");

            var result = {
                start: scheduler.view().startDate(),
                end:  scheduler.view().endDate()
            }
            return JSON.stringify(result);
        }
```

which sends the JSON data in Particular format::

```
{"start":"2014-04-29T16:00:00.000Z","end":"2014-05-06T16:00:00.000Z"}:
```

And on Server side I want to access it, for that I am using ::

```
  public virtual JsonResult Test_ReadSchedule(DateTime? start, DateTime? end)
```

But I am getting null Value here.

The `Response Header` into Server call is as::

```
Cache-Control:private, s-maxage=0
Content-Length:9975
Content-Type:application/json; charset=utf-8
Date:Mon, 28 Apr 2014 08:18:31 GMT
Server:Microsoft-IIS/8.0
X-AspNet-Version:4.0.30319
X-AspNetMvc-Version:5.0
X-Powered-By:ASP.NET
X-SourceFiles:=?UTF-8?B?QzpcQ3VlXEludm9pY2VcSG9tZVxUZXN0X1JlYWRTY2hlZHVsZQ==?=
```

Comment: Please add your server call code. i.e your ajax call where you are passing this value

Comment: @Murali I have added few more details into my Question

Comment: Please add the code where you make a server call. I assumed that you will be using ajax to pass a data and answered

Answer (score 2):

No need to send JSON encoded string to MVC model binder. i.e `JSON.stringfiy is  not requied`

Just convert the plain javascript Date object to UTC Format using [<kbd>**toUTCString()**</kbd>](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Date/toUTCString) and send

```
var postData= {
            start: scheduler.view().startDate(),
            end:  scheduler.view().endDate()
        }

$.post('/controller/action', { start: postData.start.toUTCString(), 
    end: postData.end.toUTCString() }, function (result) {

});
```